# excel.Application.ShowWindowInTaskBar=false is not working

Tags: c#

Can anyone please let me know how to hide the excel application from the taskbar.

I have tried with the below code:

```
excel.Application.ShowWindowInTaskBar=false
```

but still it is still displaying in the taskbar.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835298(v=office.14).aspx), you'll see that that's not what it does.

Comment: Quote: "This object, member, or enumeration is deprecated and is not intended to be used in your code".  So don't use it.  Only other way is to set the Visible property to false.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. If I use Application Visible=false then complete application will is hidden. But i want to show the excel apllication in the window but not in taskbar.